# is it best practice use .xib files?

Tags: iphone, ios

i would like to know if is it a good practice use .xib files to draw/interact with user interface. Whats the benefits using a xib file? And if i dont use it, just init a viewcontroller and draw/position objects on hard code is it a best practice?Whats the benefits? Im taking about it, because there are some configs cannot be done in .xib, just in hard code. Make a universal app, with internationalization is it better use .xib or can be done all in hard code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is a matter of "best practice". If you have a fairly complex layout where there are many subviews that need to be placed in a particular relationship to each other, then it is much easier to do in a xib or storyboard. For universal apps, you normally would have separate xibs or storyboards for the iPad and iPhone versions. As far as internationalizations, a lot of the problems associated with that can be handled with layout constraints (to automatically change the size of labels for instance), and there is discussion of this in the WWDC 2012 talk, "Auto Layout By Example".

Comment: so you think use a xib help more then dont have?I know its simple to layout. I thought best practice because do a project universal and internationalization should be planned. And some properties cannot be setted in xib files so i need to set other properties hard code(in view controllers)..doesnt it makes app more confused? Thats why I'm trying to create my perspect about use or not use xib files to dont neeed to face to many problems.

Comment: @JuanMunhoesJunior, it's hard to say without knowing the specifics of your project. I don't think it's a problem to mix xibs or storyboards with code. It's pretty common practice to use both. You can do the majority of your layout in the xib, and add only those things that you can't get from the xib, in code.

Comment: I thought it was not a good practice mix xibs/storyboards elements and set other properties to style/custom elements. Also as you say, there are a lot of problems with layout constraints, and a universal app without xib to separete the files become more difficult.. so i'm starting planning using xib files. Thank you for you explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the requirement and need.

Most of the time IB fulfills your requirement, so no need to code for all the GUI stuffs, but you should know how you can create GUI from code.

For iphone you can cover all your need but with macos a large controls and nested controls will put you into trouble.

So its upto you, which way you feel simpler.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This help me to open my mind about xib files.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  The reality is you want to use all the tools available to you.

You can create a UI much quicker and easier using storyboards than trying to figure it out in code.  You also get instant feedback on what it will look like without having to recompile.  It's sometimes easier to see something, than try to imagine what it will look like.

This doesn't mean you shouldn't know how to do the same thing in code.  I'd just fall back to code if you can't do it in the xib/storyboard.

What configs are you unable to do?  Internationalization is pretty easy using IB.  There are some great WWDC videos on IB, storyboards, and internationalization.  I'd check those out before ruling out what you can and can't do.

Comment: there isn't all properties from element in xib so you need to set it by yourself in code. But i think its a little confuse add objects there and create the IBOutlet for all objects in xib. That's true, its very simple to see the UI and position the elements. I just want to walk to a good way to do a good struct from the project to dont fall in to many problems

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally create it using Storyboard, in lieu of the xib. With storyboard you can programmatically generate the interface, segues, etc. Also you can create any UIElement in Storyboard that you can in an XIB.

Comment: yes, i like storyboards too. But its only compatible with iOS 5+ and i still worry with users that use iOS 4.0+

Comment: that is true. for backward compatibility you can't use storyboards or autolayout or any of those nice features.